# When Sayyidna Ibrahim(Peace be Upon him) said this dua?

Tags: history, prophet-ibrahim

I am very interested in life of Sayyidna Ibrahim(Peace be Upon him) but i am only looking for reliable reference for information

رَبِّ هَبْ لِى حُكْمًۭا وَأَلْحِقْنِى بِٱلصَّـٰلِحِينَ ٨٣

When Sayyidna Ibrahim(Peace be Upon him) said this dua?

When his father asked him to go out of house and he was teenager and he was completely alone?

or

When he was leaving his country and he was only having Hazrat Sara and Prophet Lut(Peace be Upon) with him?